# How can I configure a txqueuelen value to persist on reboot?

Tags: linux, networking, centos

In CentOS 4.x, I can set the txqueuelen parameter on a network interface with "ifconfig eth0 txqueuelen 1000".  However, this is lost when the machine reboots -- which configuration file should I use to set the persistent value of this parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do things like this inside /etc/rc.local.

Comment: For the moment so do I, but I was wondering if there was an appropriate place in /etc/sysconfig or so.